tracking solana transfers from wallet via python
I am trying to retrieve all solana transfers from an exchange wallet via the solana json api.
My current process is:

send a post request with "method": "getSignaturesForAddress".
get the transaction details of the signature with "method": "getTransaction".
check if the transaction is a solana transfer (and not any other type of transaction).
store the transaction information in a pandas database for further processing.

The method of first retrieving the signature and only then checking if it is a solana transfer seems pretty cumbersome to me.
Is there an easier method to access the last 100 transactions from a specific wallet address that is free to use?
My expected output is similar to the solscan.io SOL transfer tab for any particular wallet, giving a sender, receiver, sol amount and timestamp of transfer.
Current code:
import requests
import json

# Set the Solana RPC endpoint
solana_endpoint = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com'

# Sender address to monitor
sender_address = 'ASTyfSima4LLAdDgoFGkgqoKowG1LZFDr9fAQrg7iaJZ'

def get_signatures_for_address(address, before=None):
    limit = 100  # Max limit per request
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    params = {
        "limit": limit,
    }
    if before:
        params["before"] = before

    body = json.dumps({
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "getSignaturesForAddress",
        "params": [
            address,
            params
        ]
    })
    response = requests.post(solana_endpoint, headers=headers, data=body)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json().get('result', [])
    return []

def get_transaction_details(signature):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    body = json.dumps({
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "getTransaction",
        "params": [
            signature,
            "jsonParsed"
        ]
    })
    response = requests.post(solana_endpoint, headers=headers, data=body)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json().get('result', {})
    return {}

def analyze_transactions(address):
    last_signature = None
    sol_transfers = []

    while True:
        print('a')
        signatures = get_signatures_for_address(address, last_signature)
        if not signatures:
            break  # No more transactions to fetch

        for signature_data in signatures:
            print('b')
            transaction_detail = get_transaction_details(signature_data['signature'])
            print('c')
            transaction = transaction_detail.get('transaction', {})
            message = transaction.get('message', {})

            for instruction in message.get('instructions', []):
                print('d')
                if instruction.get('programId') == '11111111111111111111111111111111':  # Check for system program
                    parsed = instruction.get('parsed', {})
                    if parsed.get('type') == 'transfer':
                        info = parsed.get('info', {})
                        sols = info['lamports'] / 10**9
                        sol_transfers.append({'recipient': info['destination'], 'amount': sols, 'signature': signature_data['signature']})
                        print(sols)
            
            last_signature = signature_data['signature']  # Update to fetch the next batch

    return sol_transfers

# Running the analysis and printing the results
results = analyze_transactions(sender_address)
for result in results:
    print(f"Recipient: {result['recipient']}, Amount: {result['amount']} SOLs, Signature: {result['signature']}")

Thank you!

This is the way to do it through the normal Solana RPC unfortunately, via the two separate calls.
